# How to parse file as an argument to python function?

Tags: python, function

Currently, I do have following script with multiple sub tasks and I want to create each sub task as a function and provide same file as an input to all functions.

current :

```
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as my_file:
    print(my_file.append())
    print(my_file.split())
```

Want:

```
import sys

def append(file)
    do something
    return;
def split(file)
    do something
    return;
def main()
    append(file)
    split(file)
main()
```

So I want to pass file/dir name at a run time.

Comment: What is the problem now?

Comment: Hello Srini, I am trying to parse file/dict to my function as an argument so I can provide 1 input to all functions.

Comment: You probably want to check out `argparse`  https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html

Comment: @user2231154 I can imagine multiple problems here; you should be more specific what the actual problem is. Is it that you cannot get the file name from the ``sys.argv`` or is it that the file is consumed after first read or ...?

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use argparse, in orderto solve your problem

https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html